# Server side claims caching with Owin Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, claims-based-identity, owin

I have an application that used to use `FormsAuthentication`, and a while ago I switched it to use the `IdentityModel` from `WindowsIdentityFramework` so that I could benefit from claims based authentication, but it was rather ugly to use and implement. So now I'm looking at `OwinAuthentication`.

I'm looking at `OwinAuthentication` and the `Asp.Net Identity` framework. But the `Asp.Net Identity` framework's only implementation at the moment uses `EntityModel` and I'm using `nHibernate`. So for now I'm looking to try bypassing `Asp.Net Identity` and just use the `Owin Authentication` directly. I was finally able to get a working login using the tips from "[How do I ignore the Identity Framework magic and just use the OWIN auth middleware to get the claims I seek?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885569/how-do-i-ignore-the-identity-framework-magic-and-just-use-the-owin-auth-middlewa/18923770#18923770)", but now my cookie holding the claims is rather large. When I used the `IdentityModel` I was able to use a server side caching mechanism that cached the claims on the server and the cookie just held a simple token for the cached information. Is there a similar feature in `OwinAuthentication`, or would I have to implement it myself?

I expect I'm going to be in one of these boats...

2. The cookie stays as 3KB, oh well it's a little large.
3. Enable a feature similar to `IdentityModel`'s SessionCaching in `Owin` that I don't know about.
4. Write my own implementation to cache the information causing the cookie to bloat and see if I can hook it up when I configure `Owin` at application startup.
5. I'm doing this all wrong and there's an approach I've not thought of or I'm misusing something in `Owin`.

   ```
   public class OwinConfiguration
   {
       public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
       {
           app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
           {
               AuthenticationType = "Application",
               AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
               CookieHttpOnly = true,
               CookieName = "Application",
               ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
               LoginPath = "/Login",
               LogoutPath = "/Logout",
               ReturnUrlParameter="ReturnUrl",
               SlidingExpiration = true,
               Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
               {
                   OnValidateIdentity = async context =>
                   {
                       //handle custom caching here??
                   }
               }
               //CookieName = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + ExternalAuthentication.ExternalCookieName,
               //ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
           });
       }
   }
   ```

**UPDATE**
I was able to get the desired effect using the information Hongye provided and I came up with the below logic...

```
Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
{
    OnValidateIdentity = async context =>
    {
        var userId = context.Identity.GetUserId(); //Just a simple extension method to get the ID using identity.FindFirst(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) and account for possible NULLs
        if (userId == null) return;
        var cacheKey = "MyApplication_Claim_Roles_" + userId.ToString();
        var cachedClaims = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey] as IEnumerable<Claim>;
        if (cachedClaims == null)
        {
            var securityService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISecurityService>(); //My own service to get the user's roles from the database
            cachedClaims = securityService.GetRoles(context.Identity.Name).Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.RoleName));
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey] = cachedClaims;
        }
        context.Identity.AddClaims(cachedClaims);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a custom implementation of the ASP.NET Identity? There are already implementations on NuGet.

Comment: There weren't any at the time when I was dealing with this, what ones are you referring to?

Comment: Nhibernate.AspNet.Identity and also AspNet.Identity.NHibernate (I created this using SharpArchitecture and FluentNHibernate. It's a prerelease version though)

Comment: There is a field on the CookieAuthenticationOptions object called "SessionStore" which is described as "An optional container in which to store the identity across requests. When used, only a session identifier is sent to the client. This can be used to mitigate potential problems with very large identities."  This seems like what you are trying to do.  Unfortunately, I couldn't find any reference about how to actually create one of these SessionStores.

Comment: ***Claim*** is `System.Security.Claims.Claim` ? Code for `GetUserId` extension?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OWIN cookie authentication middleware doesn't support session caching like feature yet. #2 is not an options.

#3 is the right way to go. As Prabu suggested, you should do following in your code:

OnResponseSignIn:

- Save context.Identity in cache with a unique key(GUID)
- Create a new ClaimsIdentity embedded with the unique key
- Replace context.Identity with the new identity

OnValidateIdentity:

- Get the unique key claim from context.Identity
- Get the cached identity by the unique key
- Call context.ReplaceIdentity with the cached identity

I was going to suggest you to gzip the cookie, but I found that OWIN already did that in its TicketSerializer. Not an option for you.

Comment: The Claims that are causing the size of the cookie to inflate in my case are the roles used for permissions throughout the site. Is there a reason I should cache and replace the identity in it's entirety, or can I leave the identity intact and just cache and add the missing claims `ClaimTypes.Role` in the `OnValidateIdentity` task?

Comment: Sure. You can definitely customize the code to meet your app's requirement. What I posted is a generic way to reference cookie from server cache.

Comment: full source code sample for `Create a new ClaimsIdentity embedded with the unique key` and `Replace context.Identity with the new identity` ?

Answer (score 8):

```
Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
{
    OnResponseSignIn = async context =>
    {
        // This is the last chance before the ClaimsIdentity get serialized into a cookie. 
        // You can modify the ClaimsIdentity here and create the mapping here. 
        // This event is invoked one time on sign in. 
    }, 
    OnValidateIdentity = async context => 
    {
        // This method gets invoked for every request after the cookie is converted 
        // into a ClaimsIdentity. Here you can look up your claims from the mapping table. 
    }
}
```

Comment: I already knew about that section of code, and copy/pasting it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Check out the OnResponseSignIn event that I have shown above and the comment with in it. OnValidateIdentity as I have mentioned is invoked for every request. Essentially there are 2 points - OnResponseSignIn create the mapping, OnValidateIdentity - look up the claims.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement IAuthenticationSessionStore to store cookies into database.

Here's example for storing cookie in redis.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
SessionStore = new RedisSessionStore(new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector)),
LoginPath = new PathString("/Auth/LogOn"),
LogoutPath = new PathString("/Auth/LogOut"),

});
```

Check out full example [at here](https://github.com/chuongxl/Rhasta.Owin.Security.Cookies.Store.Redis/blob/master/Rhasta.Owin.Security.Cookies.Store/Rhasta.Owin.Security.Cookies.Store.Redis/RedisSessionStore.cs)

Comment: if auth cookie will be saved in db then what will be stored at client side ?

Comment: only session identifier is stored at client side