# Maintaining request state in a service hosted OWIN application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I created a REST service using WebAPI 2.  I then created a Windows service to wrap the API.

In WebAPI project, there were a couple of places I was using HttpContext.Current.Items dictionary to persist some metadata (during authentication) to avoid a second call to the DB later on in the request.

From what I understand, HttpContext.Current does not exist in OWIN.  What I am trying to figure out is how I should persist data for only one request cycle.

- Is there a way to do this out of the box or is there a library that would provide what I need?
- Should I just roll my own?

Comment: Look at this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192428/server-side-claims-caching-with-owin-authentication

Comment: @0leg, thanks for the link.  I looked at some of the forms/cookie based auth stuff OWIN provides, but that's really not what I am looking to do.  I don't need to persist data between requests, only in the same request

Answer (score 0):

What about the `Properties` collection of `HttpRequestMessage`? You can store per-request objects in this dictionary.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.properties(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.properties%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)