# How to add some claims to ClaimsIdentity but do not serialize them into the cookie

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

I am using ASP.NET Identity 2 with cookie authentication. I want to add permissions of a user to the current ClaimsPrincipal but because there could be many permissions and a cookie is limited in size I don't want to serialize all claims of the identity into the cookie. I want to load the claims during login and cache them server-side. Where do I have to hook in to add the claims to the current principal on each request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The interface [IAuthenticationSessionStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.iauthenticationsessionstore%28v=vs.113%29.aspx%20%22%22) is exactly what I need. With an implementation of that interface, setting an instance of it on the [CookieAuthenticationOptions.SessionStore property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.sessionstore%28v=vs.113%29.aspx), you can decide how to persist the whole ClaimsPrincipal during the requests without serializing it into the cookie.

Tarzan, pardon, Vittorio Bertocci is presenting details to the interface [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/05/11/owin-protocol-middleware-cookies-and-reference-mode-sessions-we-need-your-feedback/).

Comment: Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19192428/809357. Can be relevant.

Comment: Thank you very much, @trailmax. Serializing AuthenticationTicket as the IAuthenticationSessionStore requires is no fun! Adding claims after the Identity is deserialized by the OWIN middleware from the cookie is much easier.